# idiomatic python, manage default arguments in functions

Tags: python, arguments, default, idioms

I usually encounter that most of the people manage default arguments values in functions or methods like this:

```
def foo(L=None):
  if L is None:
    L = []
```

However i see other people doing something like:

```
def foo(L=None):
  L = L or []
```

I don't know if i a missing something but, why most of the people use the first approach instead the second? Are they equally the same thing?, seems that the second is clearer and shorter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not equal.
First approach checks exactly, that given arg `L` is `None`.
Second checks, that L is true in python way. In python, if you check in condition the list, rules are the following:

1. List is empty, then it is False
2. True otherwise

So what's the difference between mentioned approaches? Compare this code.

First:

```
def foo(L=None):
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append('x')
    return L

>>> my_list = []
>>> foo(my_list)
>>> my_list
['x']
```

Second:

```
def foo(L=None):
    L = L or []
    L.append('x')
    return L

>>> my_list = []
>>> foo(my_list)
>>> my_list
[]
```

So first didn't create a new list, it used the given list. But second creates the new one.

Answer (score 1):

The two are not equivalent if the argument is a false-y value. This doesn't matters often, as many false-y values aren't suitable arguments to most functions where you'd do this. Still, there are conceivable situations where it can matter. For example, if a function is supposed to fill a dictionary (creating a new one if none is given), and someone passes an empty ordered dictionary instead, then the latter approach would incorrectly return an ordinary dictionary.

That's not my primary reason for always using the `is None` version though. I prefer it as it is more explicit and the fact that `or` returns one of its operands isn't intuitive to me. I like to forget about it as long as I can ;-) The extra line is not a problem, this is relatively rare.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they don't know of the second one?  I tend to use the first.

Actually there is a difference.  The second one will let L = [] if you pass anything that evaluates to Boolean false. 0 empty string or others.  The first will only do that if no L is passed or it was passed as None.